# For Loop in R yielding fewer values

Tags: r, for-loop, rmysql

I have the following for loop in R to extract data from 4 My SQL tables. The dataframe length refers to the

```
     for (i in length(dataframe)){

     sql1 <- paste("SELECT T.TenantLookupID, T.TenantShortCode, 
         B.BusinessUnitShortCode, C.CampaignShortCode
            from TenantLookup AS T
            JOIN BusinessUnitLookup AS B ON T.TenantLookupID = B.TenantLookupID
            JOIN CampaignLookup AS C ON C.TenantLookupID = B.TenantLookupID 
            where T.TenantID = '611c5d1c_f0bc_4bd4_b1c1_f6800d50fc34' AND B.BusinessUnitID = 0
            AND C.CampaignID =", i,sep="")

      dataframe2<-dbGetQuery(jobdbconn, sql1)}
```

The code should yield 30 values 
However it yields far fewer values. Can Someone suggest a solution

```
    TenantLookupID TenantShortCode BusinessUnitShortCode CampaignShortCode
    1            572             NOn                     w               uvn
    2            572             NOn                     w               Mxc
    3            572             NOn                     w               W0H
    4            572             NOn                     w               qr5
    5            572             NOn                     w               ABy
```

The format is right but at the number is far lesser than expected

Comment: you are only looping once.  try `for (i in 1:length(dataframe))`

Answer (score 1):

This is not a range, only a single value:

```
 for (i in length(dataframe)) {
```

For all values from 1 to length(dataframe) use:

```
 for (i in 1:length(dataframe)) {
```

**EDIT:**

In addition, at the end of your loop you are overwriting your results dataframe each time.  Perhaps

```
dataframe2<-dbGetQuery(jobdbconn, sql1)
```

Should be

```
dataframe2<-rbind(dataframe2, dbGetQuery(jobdbconn, sql1))
```

Something like this:

```
dataframe2 <- data.frame()
for (i in length(dataframe)){

 sql1 <- paste("SELECT T.TenantLookupID, T.TenantShortCode, 
     B.BusinessUnitShortCode, C.CampaignShortCode
        from TenantLookup AS T
        JOIN BusinessUnitLookup AS B ON T.TenantLookupID = B.TenantLookupID
        JOIN CampaignLookup AS C ON C.TenantLookupID = B.TenantLookupID 
        where T.TenantID = '611c5d1c_f0bc_4bd4_b1c1_f6800d50fc34' AND B.BusinessUnitID = 0
        AND C.CampaignID =", i,sep="")

  dataframe2<-rbind(dataframe2, dbGetQuery(jobdbconn, sql1)}
```

hth

Comment: I have tried Both. It doesnt seem to work. In Fact the code sometimes gives 81 rows, sometimes 3. I Am puzzled

Comment: @VishnuRaghavan see edit.  perhaps the rbind issue will help as well.  Note sure why you are getting different numbers of rows on different runs though.

Comment: @ Eric Thank You Sir. I Will check the same.

Comment: I have tried the same again. It hasnt helped so far.

Comment: I have incidentally, used one set of characters from the column to run the code. It seems to work now